# I don't know how to fix this attributeerror: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'grid'

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to build a budget manager with `tkinter`. I've tried a lot of things to fix this problem, but nothing seems to work. The oddest thing about this is I'm working with an entry, not a string.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Budget Manager")
budget = 2300

# Creating an entry to add/remove to the budget
add_budget_entry = Entry(root, width = 50).get()
add_budget_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

# Creating the function that's called when button "Add/remove from budget" is pressed.
def AddBudget():
    global budget
    budget += add_budget_entry
    return budget

# Creating the label to display the current budget
budget_label = Label(root, text = budget, padx = 20, pady = 10)
budget_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

# Creating the button that will add the given amount to the budget.
add_budget_button = Button(root, text = "Add/remove from budget", command = AddBudget())
add_budget_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

The error seems rather simple to solve, but I don't know if it's just because I'm new to `tkinter`. The thing that confuses me the most is that the error is produced at the line where I'm creating a grid for an entry, not a string.

Here's the full error so you can see specifically where the error is produced:

```py
line 9, in <module>
    add_budget_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

Comment: `add_budget_entry = Entry(root, width = 50).get()` - `Entry.get()` returns the entry's current text as a string, you can't call `grid` on a string

Comment: Change `Entry(...).get()` to just `Entry(...)` and change `budget += add_budget_entry` to `budget += float(add_budget_entry.get())`.

Comment: `command = AddBudget()` *calls `AddBudget` now*, and uses *the result* as the callback.

Comment: " is produced at the line where I'm creating a grid for an entry, not a string." In your own words, why do you think it is an entry at this point? (Hint: what is the effect of `.get()` on the previous line?)

Comment: Thank you it semed to work.